# AWS RedHat Enterprise EC2 Billing Confusion

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Does AWS RHEL EC2 billis per second or per hour?

So If I run an ec2 for 30min, will it be billed for just 30 min? or an hour?
I've seen that aws supports per-second billing for linux, is it applicable for RHEL too? As it has seperate cost assositat with it.

Also using Spot Instances.

So in summery will I be billed by hour or by seconds?

Comment: posted an answer with pricing specifically for rhel instances. If it helped you an upvote/acceptance would help others in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to faq
https://aws.amazon.com/partners/redhat/faqs/

Whether it is on demand of spot instances

> Red Hat Enterprise Linux on Amazon EC2 is offered at either a flat, hourly rate with no commitment (On-Demand or Spot Instances) or through a one-time, upfront payment (Reserved Instances). Both purchase options include Amazon EC2 compute charges and Red

Comment: @Anwar Hossain, In short, it's hourly. As you can see in the link provided by @Jatin Mehrotra, ` Pricing is per instance-hour consumed for each instance type. Partial instance-hours consumed are billed as full hours`.

Comment: Got it, Thanks. So if I want to go for partial bill, I should go for CentOS?